# Extracting a secret from a SHA-1 hashing algorithm

Tags: sha-1

Assuming there is a web service that returns the following to an unauthenticated user:

```
SHA-1(known_prefix + user_input + backend_secret)
```

where `+` is string concatenation, `known_prefix` is known to the attacker, `user_input` can be specified almost arbitrarily (maybe only printable ascii characters, but arbitrary length), and the `backend_secret` is something that the attacker should not know.

Is there an intelligent way, by specifying different `user_input` strings and analyzing the returned SHA-1 hash, how an attacker could extract the `backend_secret`? Something better than bruteforcing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an intelligent way, by specifying different `user_input` strings and analyzing the returned SHA-1 hash, how an attacker could extract the `backend_secret`?

There is a possible way to get some information on `backend_secret` (at least, the value of the first several bytes); this might speed up the follow-up brute force search.

This is based on finding a SHA-1 collision, where $SHA1(A) = SHA1(B)$ (and, in particular, the internal SHA-1 state immediately after processing $A$ and $B$ is the same), and has these further properties:

- $A, B$ both start with `known_prefix`
- The last byte of $A, B$ are the same
- If we replace the last byte of $A, B$ with a different value, they are not a collision.

I believe that it is feasible to find such a collision.

The probe is obvious, we query for both known_prefix + user_input = A (less the last byte), and known_prefix + user_input = B (less the last byte).  If the first byte of backend_secret was the common last byte of A, B, then the results of the two queries are the same (and hence we have learned the first byte of backend_secret).  If they are different, we have learned what the first byte of backend_secret was not (and we can try again with a different collision with a different final last byte).

We can then proceed with the same attack to recover the second (and then third, etc) bytes.  The requirements on the collision become stricter; it is likely that the known $O(2^{60})$ collision attacks will no longer yield applicable collisions, however a straight-forward $O(2^{80})$ birthday attack will, and so this would yield a $O(2^{88})$ effort per byte (which may or may not be considered feasible, depending on whether we're looking at this as a cryptodesigner or an adversary).

Comment: Yes! Addition: we need $A$, $B$, `known_prefix + user_input + probed_start_of_backend_secret` to be of the same size multiple of 512 bits (32 bytes).

Comment: Alright nice, so this works because of the Merkle–Damgård construction. I'm wondering if there is some even more efficient way that works directly with the compression function...

Comment: @dan-ros: doesn't look extremely likely.  The known issues with the SHA-1 compression function are the collision attacks (which I exploited) and the fact that finding 'fixed points' (that is, given a message block, what initial state is mapped to itself) is easy (and that second observation doesn't appear to be exploitable)