# On the exposition of SHA-1 attack (known_prefix + user_input + backend_secret)

Tags: brute-force-attack, sha-1, collision-attack

In [this question on `sha1(known_prefix + user_input + backend_secret)`](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/107983/111411), [an answer states that is realistically possible to find the first few bytes of `backend_secret` quicker than brute force](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/107984/111411).

---

**Changing only `user_input`, how can I find *some* information about the constant value of `backend_secret`?**

I give the known prefix of `stackexchange`, and the backend secret of `107983` (as a string) for this demonstration. You can only change `user_input`.

```
user_input="question"

KNOWN_PREFIX="stackexchange"
backend_secret="107983"

# bf24cd561d758104993d3fe6f58b44e6209c7bcd
printf "%s%s%s" "$KNOWN_PREFIX" "$user_input" "$backend_secret" | sha1sum
```

---

[Excerpts from the answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/107984/111411) where I try to follow along:

> The probe is obvious, we query for both `known_prefix + user_input = A (less the last byte)`, and `known_prefix + user_input = B (less the last byte)` [where `sha1(A) = sha1(B)`].

To do this, SHA-1 would need to already be broken? Is it saying we need to find `bf24cd561d758104993d3fe6f58b44e6209c7bxx` with `sha1(known_prefix + user_input + backend_secret)`, where `xx` and `user_input` can be anything?

> If the first byte of `backend_secret` *was the common last byte of `A`, `B`*, then the results of the two queries are the same (and hence we have learned the first byte of backend_secret)

`backend_secret` is not known to us, and cannot be changed. The last byte of `A` and `B` is the last byte to `backend_secret` (since `sha1(A) = sha1(known_prefix + user_input + backend_secret)`). Is the answer saying this can happen if `backend_secret` is chosen poorly by the backend? Does `backend_secret` need to be of a specific size?

> If they are different, we have learned what the first byte of `backend_secret` was not (and we can try again with a different collision with a different final last byte).

Since `backend_secret` is a constant, how can we "try again with a different final last byte"?

Comment: @kelalaka I want explanation for how to use poncho's answer for the general case. My small secret is only example (6 bytes is not too small, it's already 48 bits - an attacker does not know it is made up of only digits).

Comment: You asked, the details, that I gave my time for your understanding, and neither upvoted, nor accepted nor asked still some unclear part. Thank you. Deleted my answer.